# Google Earth Engine, Landsat scene extraction?

Tags: landsat, google-earth-engine

I would like to ask if someone knows how to extract collection of scenes (equal to the exact size of the Landsat 7 scene) from image collection I need an area around Bangalore, India? So I would have the stack of scenes.
For now I have this code where I have added area corners manually (and while editing the number of images was changing. The largest one I got was 168):

```js
var l7r = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE7_L1T"),
real = {"opacity":1,"bands":["B3","B2","B1"],"min":76,"gamma":2.07};//real
Map.setCenter(77.40, 13.14,7);
//input study regionr
var LL=[76.48, 12.31];   //Lower left corner
var UR=[78.15, 13.69];   //Upper right corner
var l7rf=l7r.filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(LL)).filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(UR));
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(l7rf.first()),real,'raw');
```

But I am not sure if all images available from the 1999 till nowadays are included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what I have done. I have checked name of one of the images in the collection. At the place where numbers start first 3 corresponded to the path, and next 3 numbers correspond to the row of an image. So that is how I have changed my code:

```js
var l7r = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE7_L1T")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 144))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 51));
```

And I have used these code to check image names, and dates of the images:

```js
// This function adds a band representing the image timestamp.
var addTime = function(image) {
      return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start'));
};

// Map the function over the collection and display the result.
print(l7r.map(addTime));
```